# Is it possible to mix Docker containers with LXC containers

Tags: server, docker, lxc

One of the major challenges we're facing with dockerizing our apps is that there are a lot of dependencies that need to be installed. LXC has been great at that as they provide a "full linux system".
However, we're faced with the need to add already prepared docker containers to the cluster that we're already running.

So is it possible to mix docker containers with LXC containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and also feasible. Docker and LXC/LXD serve different purposes.

- Docker containers are geared towards running specific applications inside each container, and thus each container is more of a "one-trick pony".
- LXC containers are intended to provide a persistent VM-like system in each container, so these are better for experiments and testing on full systems.

However, note that Docker and LXC/LXD are two different ecosystems, that aren't aware of each other. So any orchestration and interaction between the two needs to be set up separately for each.

Also, please see this image from one of Mark's presentations, that show the relation between different container technologies.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
One more thing, I'm aware that Kubernetes supports both Docker and LXD containers. Can one mix them in a cluster?

Comment: I don't think so. I believe orchestration must be set within one container technology - but I don't know for sure if it's possible.